# I'm trying to get data from my firestore database but it keeps returning an error saying receiver null. my code is written below

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get back the first name of a user from my firestore database, but it keeps bringing up the same error.so every time I press the run icon, it returns an error saying receiver null. Kindly help or, better yet, tell me where I am going wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_sh1/screens/categories.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import '../main.dart';
import '../utils/color_utils.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class Highiest_Education extends StatefulWidget {
  CollectionReference docUser =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("EMPLOYEES");

  @override
  State<Highiest_Education> createState() => _Highiest_EducationState();
  late final FirebaseFirestore db;

  FirestoreSnippets(db) {
    // TODO: implement FirestoreSnippets
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}

class _Highiest_EducationState extends State<Highiest_Education> {
  get db => FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text(
            "Personal Profile",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
            hexStringToColor("CB2B93"),
            hexStringToColor("9546C4"),
            hexStringToColor("5E61F4")
          ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                20, MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2, 20, 0),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Row(children: [
                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "TR",
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final LEO = await db
                        .collection("EMPLOYEES")
                        .where("First name", isEqualTo: "leonard")
                        .get()
                        .then(
                          (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
                          onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
                        );
                    print("${LEO.First_name}");
                  },
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                  label: Text("Next"),
                )
              ])
            ]),
          )),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Categories()));
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          label: Text("check"),
        ));
  }
}
```

So, as you can see, I tried to call back the LEO as a list from which I could derive the first name from my database, but it keeps bringing the same error saying receiver null

Comment: youre getting error because this `get db => FirebaseFirestore.instance;` is wrong.

Comment: Ok so what's the correct format because I've tried multiple options n they bear no fruit. kindly just type the correct format or send me a link to a book i can read please